# Fazer Download de um arquivo gerado no backend pelo Angular2+

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

Ola, eu estou com problemas em fazer do download de um arquivo gerado pelo backend no meu projeto angular, eu tenho o seguinte metodo

```
generateXlsx(obj) {
let headers = new Headers();
let token = localStorage.getItem('token');
let client = localStorage.getItem('client');
let uid = localStorage.getItem('uid');
headers.append('access-token', token);
headers.append('client', client);
headers.append('uid', uid);
return this.http.get(this.xlsxUrl, { params: obj, headers: headers });
}
```

Quando ele e chamado ele vai para Url de download do meu arquivo, porem quando eu chamo essa Rota/Url via angular, ele não faz o download, porem na aba de Network o arquivo esta salvo em response, segue print do resultado
[image: Codigo gerado no response]

No meu FrontEnd, quando eu aperto um botão e chamado o seguinte metodo

```
generatePlanilha(obj) {
this.api.generateXlsx(obj)
  .subscribe(response => {
    if (response) {
      console.log("Planilha Gerada");
    }
  },
    (error => { console.log("NAO GEROU PLANILJA") }));
  }
```

Eu queria saber como eu faço para baixar a resposta que esta no Network

Answer (score 1):

Você pode criar um blob a partir do response e fazer o download dele abrindo um popup com os dados:

```
 import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

 .map((res:Response) => res.text())
 .subscribe(response => {
    if (response) {
      const blob = new Blob([response], { type: 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet' });
      const url= window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
      window.open(url);
    }
  },
    (error => { console.log("NAO GEROU PLANILJA") }));
  }
```

> https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Blob
>
> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/open
>
> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2937465/what-is-correct-content-type-for-excel-files

Comment: Esta dando o seguinte erro no "[response]" [ts]
Type 'Response' is not assignable to type 'BlobPart'.
  Type 'Response' is not assignable to type 'Blob'.
    Property 'size' is missing in type 'Response'. [2322]
(parameter) response: Response

Comment: Tenta com essa modificação que fiz, `.map((res:Response) => res.text())`

Comment: agora os parametros do .map deu o seguinte erro: [ts]
Argument of type '(res: Response) => Promise<string>' is not assignable to parameter of type '(value: Response, index: number) => Promise<string>'.
  Types of parameters 'res' and 'value' are incompatible.
    Type 'import("/home/marcelo/Desktop/Mercatorio/dashboard/node_modules/@angular/http/src/static_response").Response' is not assignable to type 'Response'.
      Property 'redirected' is missing in type 'Response'. [2345]

Comment: Qual a versão do angular? Pode ter alguma mudança na importação do `map`, tenta assim : `import { map } from "rxjs/operators";`

Comment: Angular CLI: 7.0.4
Node: 8.12.0
OS: linux x64
Angular: 5.1.2, eu ja importei o map

Comment: Deveria funcionar, parece que o response que importou `import("/home/marcelo/Desktop/Mercatorio/dashboard/node_modules/@angular/http/src/static_response")` não é o correto, tenta remover essa importação e deixar o tipo como `any`

Comment: o erro permance: [ts]
Argument of type '(res: Response) => Promise<string>' is not assignable to parameter of type '(value: Response, index: number) => Promise<string>'.
  Types of parameters 'res' and 'value' are incompatible.
    Type 'import("/home/marcelo/Desktop/Mercatorio/dashboard/node_modules/@angular/http/src/static_response").Response' is not assignable to type 'Response'.
      Property 'redirected' is missing in type 'Response'. [2345]
interface Response

Comment: Alguma luz pra me dar?

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/86563/discussion-between-edson-alves-and-marcelo-henrique-dos-reis).

Comment: te chamei la no chat.